# Ajax in child page with ScriptManager in Master Page not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, master-pages, scriptmanager

So, i have this ScriptManager in the masterpage.

```
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePartialRendering="true" runat="server">
                <Scripts>
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/SIG/MasterPage/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/SIG/MasterPage/js/cufon-yui.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/SIG/MasterPage/js/cufon-georgia.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/SIG/MasterPage/js/script.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/SIG/MasterPage/js/coin-slider.min.js" />
                </Scripts>
```

And i have a child page with this code inside the contentplaceholder:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ChildrenAsTriggers="True" UpdateMode="Conditional" ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <uc1:ListarUtilizadores runat="server" id="ListarUtilizadores" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

inside the webcontroller i have one asp button that i want to be the trigger for the ajax pannel, but it isnt working.

any help pls?

Answer (score 0):

I had the tag form on the master page with some kind of bug, out of place, after correcting that it worked.